# C# serialize JSON Object to a class

Tags: c#, .net, json

I am working on Json Obejct deserielize to a class in .net VS2015 on win 7.

```
public class1
{
    [JsonProperty(TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects)]
    public Class1 data1;
    public Class2 data2;
}

public abstract Class1 
{
    some functions

}

public subClass1 : Class1
{
        public string myData1 { get; set; }
        public string myData2 { get; set; }

}
```

In my code of deserierlizing:

```
var mo = MyObject as JObject;

ParentMyClass = mo.ToObject<MyClass>();
```

I know that an abstract class cannot be instantiated.
So, subClass1 (which is one of the implementation of Class1) is serialized. 
But, subClass1 is null after deserialized.

Did I do something wrong ?

**UPDATED:**
because the code of the classes is too complex, I just simplified the logic.

Comment: Where is `MyClass` class code?

Comment: What is JObject, what is MyClass? Your question is not clear.

Comment: You can´t instantiate an abstract class. You need a concrete one that derives from the abstract one of course.

Comment: This question makes no sense. You provide a few classes, none of which show what `MyClass` is.

Comment: subClass1 is the class that inherits the abstract class, i tried to instantiate it in the process of deserielizing the JSON object. But, i do not know how.

Comment: The update to the question does not help at all. What are `MyClass`, `ParentMyClass` and `MyObject`?

Answer (score 0):

When you call `mo.ToObject<Class1>();` Newtonsoft.Json library will try to create an instance down the line. The problem is you cannot instantiate a abstract. You can see this your self by calling `var x = new Class1();` somewhere in you code. This will give you error.

That being said, one thing you could do is create another class that inherits the abstract class.

```
public class NonAbstract : Class1 {}
```

this way you will have a class that can be instantiated. And then you can do this.

```
mo.ToObject<NonAbstract >();
```

Comment: subClass1 is the class that inherits the abstract class, i tried to instantiate it in the process of deserielizing the JSON object. But, i do not know how.